# Tomcat - AJAX calls using correct JSESSIONID

Tags: jquery, r, ajax, tomcat, jsessionid

I login into a tomcat instance at `mywebsite1.web.com` where I get a JSESSIONID. As part of browsing activity I go to a different tomcat instance at `mywebsite2.web.com` - where I get a different JSESSIONID.

As part of an activity, I need to make an AJAX POST call to `mywebsite1.web.com/user_activity`. What I understand is that the JSESSIONID for `mywebsite1.web.com` will *not* be passed *unless* I pass `withCredentials` to true. In other words, if I do the following from `mywebsite2.web.com/a_random_browser_page`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: "mywebsite1.web.com/user_activity",
  global: false,
  type: "POST",
  xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
$.ajax({ data: '' });
```

Would I be sending the correct JSESSIONID (originally issued by 'mywebsite1.web.com' at the beginning) ? Do I need to set any additional headers at `mywebsite1.web.com` to get this working?

** Note **

I am setting the following headers on my response

```
("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://mywebsite2.web.com");
("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS");
("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Accept,X-Requested-With,Session")
```

I tried to hit the URL with my browser and it works successfully and shows the headers correctly on the dev console inspector. So I am not sure what's wrong here.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @LajosArpad     It didn't work even when I added `Access-control-allow-origin` header as `*`. I opened a different tab and hit that URL directly to verify that the CORS header is set correctly by `mywebsite1.web.com`